# Iterate Through Python Dict for Specific Values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am using Python 3.6 and I have a dictionary like so:

```
{
    "TYPE": {
        "0": "ELECTRIC",
        "1": "ELECTRIC",
        "2": "ELECTRIC",
        "3": "ELECTRIC",
        "4": "TELECOMMUNICATIONS"
    },
    "ID": {
        "0": 13,
        "1": 13,
        "2": 13,
        "3": 13,
        "4": 24
    },
    "1/17/2019": {
        "0": 23,
        "1": 23,
        "2": 23,
        "3": 23,
        "4": 1
    },
    "DATE": {
        "0": "1/17/2019",
        "1": "2/28/2019",
        "2": "3/5/2019",
        "3": "3/28/2019",
        "4": "1/1/2019"
    }
}
```

How can I iterate through that and access the values of only `Utility Type` and `ID`? My goal is to append them to a list of lists like so `[[ELECTRIC, 13], [ELECTRIC, 13], ...]`

Up to this point I have been able to access the values like so:

```
for key, value in addresses.items():
    if key == 'UTILITY TYPE':
        for k, v in value.items():
            print(v)
    elif key == 'ID':
        for k, v in value.items():
            print(v)
```

but I can't figure out how to append the value of `v` to my list.

Comment: Can you please show some efforts from your part?

Comment: yes, adding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = []
for key in d["TYPE"]:
    temp = [d["TYPE"][key], d["ID"][key]]
    output.append(temp)
```

OR

```
x = [[d["TYPE"][key], d["ID"][key]] for key in d["TYPE"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You could do this using `pandas` library. Also, consider trying `pd.DataFrame(d)` to see if that could be of any use to you (since I don't know your final usecase).

```py
import pandas as pd

# d is your dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
columns = df.columns
labels = df.index.tolist()
print('labels: {}\n'.format(labels))
[df[x].tolist() for x in columns]
```

**Output**:

```
labels: ['TYPE', 'ID', '1/17/2019', 'DATE']

[['ELECTRIC', 13, 23, '1/17/2019'],
 ['ELECTRIC', 13, 23, '2/28/2019'],
 ['ELECTRIC', 13, 23, '3/5/2019'],
 ['ELECTRIC', 13, 23, '3/28/2019'],
 ['TELECOMMUNICATIONS', 24, 1, '1/1/2019']]
```

### Dummy Data

```py
d = {
    "TYPE": {
        "0": "ELECTRIC",
        "1": "ELECTRIC",
        "2": "ELECTRIC",
        "3": "ELECTRIC",
        "4": "TELECOMMUNICATIONS"
    },
    "ID": {
        "0": 13,
        "1": 13,
        "2": 13,
        "3": 13,
        "4": 24
    },
    "1/17/2019": {
        "0": 23,
        "1": 23,
        "2": 23,
        "3": 23,
        "4": 1
    },
    "DATE": {
        "0": "1/17/2019",
        "1": "2/28/2019",
        "2": "3/5/2019",
        "3": "3/28/2019",
        "4": "1/1/2019"
    }
}
```